# Expanding env variables in runtime in windows shell

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, windows-shell

I got troubles with the following sample. I have a file with a list of filenames. I want to check if these files exist, e.g.:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
%SystemRoot%\sdfsdfsd.exe
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe
```

Every path contains envronment variable.

My example of `bat` file:

```
echo off  
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (filelist.txt) do (  
  if exist "%%~a" (  
    echo %%~a exists  
  ) else (  
    echo %%~a doesn't exists  
  )  
)
```

Filenames are loaded correctly, but I cmd can't find all the files. I think that cmd processor doesn't expand env variables in paths...How I can do it? Or may be there is another problem.

Or how I can replace `!` by `%` in variable and otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15116071/1630171) already had the right idea, but there's no need to resort to a subroutine. `call` will also cause the expansion of nested variables when used in conjunction with e.g. the `set` command.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (filelist.txt) do (
  call set fname=%%~a
  if exist "!fname!" (
    echo %%~a exists.
  ) else (
    echo %%~a doesn't exist.
  )
)

endlocal
```

**Edit:** As pointed out by @dbenham the delayed expansion in the above code will cause exclamation marks to vanish from filenames. This can be mitigated by moving the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` instruction inside the loop and prepend the `call set` with a `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion` to prevent `%fname%` from leaking out of the loop.

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (filelist.txt) do (
  setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
  call set fname=%%~a
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  if exist "!fname!" (
    echo %%~a exists.
  ) else (
    echo %%~a doesn't exist.
  )
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: True, but my ocd tingles at `call set varname` as `%fname%` remains defined as an orphaned environment variable after the script has exited.  `call SET` undermines `setlocal` in my opinion.

Comment: Also, the delayed expansion will corrupt any file name that contains `!` (that is rare, I know, but it does happen). The problem can be fixed by toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

Comment: @rojo `call set` doesn't leave `%fname%` defined when used inside `setlocal`.

Comment: Instead of `set fname=` at end, you could simply add a `setlocal disableDelayedExpansion` before defining fname, and another `endlocal` at the end. That way it doesn't matter whether delayed expansion was enabled or disabled upon loop entry. Now if the intent of the loop is to set some environment variables, then it gets a bit more complicated since they would have to be set after the `endlocal`(s).

Comment: @Ansgar-Wiechers, thank you! I got your second example with only one small modification: use `endlocal & endlocal` instead of `endlocal`. Because of `Maximum setlocal recursion level reached.` error. The magic is in `call set fname=%%~a` line.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `call` to force your variables in your text file to be evaluated.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (filelist.txt) do (
    call :checkExists "%%~a"
)
goto :EOF

:checkExists <filename>
if exist %1 (
    echo %~1 exists
) else (
    echo %~1 doesn't exists
)
goto :EOF
```